# Does Entity Framework DB First (EDMX) prevent proper Separation of Concerns?

Tags: entity-framework, edmx, separation-of-concerns

I am new to entity framework and MVC, and trying to understand what constitutes a good design approach for a new application.

There are several ways of using Entity Framework. However, for my project, the best looking option is DB First. I've played around with an EDMX file, and I have got as far as using the DbContext code generator to create my wrapper classes.

I plan on using the repository and unit-of-work patterns, and using ninject for DI.

However, it does not seem "proper", from a SoC point of view, that whilst my respository will hide the implementation of the data store (EF) from my code, the model classes themselves are very much EF flavoured.

It seems that using EDMX-based approaches to EF blur the separation of concerns. Only POCO support seems to allow a true separation, but POCO has some other limitations that I don't like.

Am I missing something, or does using EDMX have this drawback?

Are people using an auto mapper to convert between the entity model and another, clean, SoCced model?

thanks

Tian

Comment: How does being Entity-Framework flavoured affect the separation of concerns?

Comment: You could add a Dto layer that better represents your domain and a translation layer to translate entities to Dtos.  I have found that flow very complex transforms, Auto Mapper is more work than writing and unit testing the mapping routines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a strong opinion on the Separation Of Concerns question, but I have used both the standard ADO.Net version of EF and POCO and it is not difficult at all to customise the output of the the T4 code generation script for POCO to address any concerns you have about the structure of the objects created. That sounds like it would probably be a good starting point for what you are looking to do.

Once you know you are looking for T4 templates there are quite a few tutorials and a lot of helpful SO questions that can give you an idea of what you need to do.